# How to log LREAL values to file?

Tags: precision, plc, structured-text

I'm new to PLC programming and I'm trying to keep track of an LREAL variable in some existing structured-text code.  I'm using Omron's CX-Programmer with a simulated CJ2M.

My first instinct was to log all changes in value to SD card, using WRITE_TEXT() .  Since I need a string value to write, I had hoped that LREAL_TO_STRING() would do the trick, but it appears that function does not exist.

How could I best log that value without losing precision?

---

Edit:  I managed to work around this problem.  Having been told CX-Programmer's SD card emulation could be unreliable, I simply wrote the values to an array and examined the contents of those memory locations with the built in tools. I could also export these values into a file if needed.  This approach limits the amount of recorded data to available space in the simulated PLC memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CXP you can't convert real into a string. You have to do the conversion yourself.

If you want to know if you can do any other conversion you can follow the table [here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/346543/Omron-Cx-Programmer-V8-1.html?page=171&term=WRITE_TEXT&selected=1#manual).